# Why my bind_result code removing '/' from value?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

My MySQL database stores a value with forward slash but it get returned without slash when called using prepare statement from my php code.

Value stored in database field `service_no` is `JP20180217/02`. But the following code echoing `JP2018021702`

```
$opening_date = '2018-02-17';
$stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT service_no FROM service_ticket WHERE 
opening_date = '$opening_date' ORDER BY service_ticket_id DESC LIMIT 1");
if($stmt->execute()){
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($ticket_number);
  $stmt->fetch();
  echo $ticket_number;
}
```

Please identify why this happening. I am really in trouble.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you should use `bind_param()` instead of substituting a string into the SQL.

Comment: You said you're using a stored procedure. Where is that in your code? It's just an ordinary `SELECT` query.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would do this. Are you sure the slash is in the table? Is there any other code you're not showing us? Maybe there's Javascript on the client removing the slash?

Comment: Sorry it's not stored procedure. I am using prepared statement. This is pure PHP code. My database actually stores slash.

Comment: Do you see the slash if you do View Source?

Comment: I am checking in browser console. This PHP code sending data over Ajax.

Comment: If it's AJAX, maybe the problem is in the Javascript code that's displaying it. Check the Network tab to see what's actually being echoed.

Comment: Checked the network tab. the problem still exists.

Comment: What does `echo strlen($ticket_number);` show?